# filter list of Objects java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to filter employee based records from a list.

my employee object looks like

```
<pre>new Employee(EmpID, EmpName,"month-year",Transition)
```

I can have more than one object per Employee with different transition and month-year eg `<pre>Hired , Bench, joinedproject,releasedproject,resign` and respective dates

Now I want to fetch month-year from first and last object per employee .

for eg

```
<pre>new Employee(1, "alex","02-2016","Hired")
new Employee(1, "alex","02-2016","Bench")
new Employee(1, "alex","03-2016","Project")
new Employee(1, "alex","12-2016","Resign")
new Employee(1, "alex","01-2017","Exit")
```

for above example  I would be getting dates as "02-2016" and "01-2017"

I hope my question is clear.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose your `month-year` is a `String`, is it always in the format `00-00`? Is January 0 or 1? And is the date the termination date or the hiring date?

Comment: Yes my date is in String and its 1-2016 format . January is 1

Comment: still a few precisions needed... When you say "3 month of period", what do you want exactly? In the last three months?

Comment: I want to remove employees from list who join and left in 3 months . I am trying to check quarterly exits of employees from a company.  How many employees joins and leave company within 3 months of time

Comment: @shmosel  How to filter and remove from collection

Comment: So employees who were hired for less than three months? Given the current format of your `Employee` class, I only see one date, you would need at least two dates, one for employment and the other for termination.

Comment: See `Collection.removeIf()` or `Stream.filter()`.

Comment: @Mritunjay Without more info, all I can tell you is you're going to need the [`Collection#removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method.

Comment: @MikaelF i have updated my question

Comment: @MikaelF Thanks for the pointers

Comment: It’s like it’s a different question now, you may consider asking a new one instead. Anyway, is the list always sorted by month-year (at least per employee) as in the example? If not, do you want the first item in the list or the earliest month-year for the employee?

Comment: If for some employee there is exactly one record in the list, will that record count as both the first and the last so you want the month-year twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your problem:

```
List<Employee> list = ...

DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("MM-yyyy")
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
    .toFormatter();
list.removeIf(e -> LocalDate.parse(e.getHiringDate(), formatter)
    .until(LocalDate.parse(e.getTerminationDate(), formatter)).getMonths() < 3);
```

The long builder call at the beginning is because `LocalDate.parse` can't instanciate `LocalDate` without a day of the month, so we have to specify a default day (in this case 1).

*NOTE*: It's not clear from your question what the structure of your `Employee` class is, so I assumed it conforms to the JavaBeans pattern and provides getters for `HiringDate` and `TerminationDate` properties. You should nonetheless be able to work this solution into your existing code if your structure differs from mine.

Comment: Hello I have formatted and added detailed example for my question. Request you to please reopen my question.

Comment: If you need to parse the year-month field, why not just use `YearMonth.parse("02-2016", "MM-uuuu")`? Seems simpler to me, no need to bother with day of month.

Comment: @OleV.V. That is indeed a better idea. I simply did not know of `YearMonth`. I don't want to take credit for your idea, so I'll leave it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

To get just the first and the last month-year string for each employee you may do (with Java 8 streams):

```
    String[][] monthYears = employeeTransitions.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getId))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .map(transList -> new String[]{ transList.get(0).getMonthYear(), 
                    transList.get(transList.size() - 1).getMonthYear() })
            .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

I added one more `Employee` to your list, `new Employee(2, "mks", "02-2017", "Hired")`, to test it with more than one employee ID. The above code now yields:

```
[[02-2016, 01-2017], [02-2017, 02-2017]]
```

We notice two things here: There is no coupling to the employee IDs. For the employee I added with only one record in the list, I get the same month-year string as both the first and the last, which I suppose is OK.

To have the months associated with the employee ID is not much more complicated:

```
    Map<Integer, List<String>> monthYearPerEmployee = employeeTransitions.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getId))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> {
                 List<Employee> transitionsForEmployee = entry.getValue();
                 return Arrays.asList(transitionsForEmployee.get(0).getMonthYear(), 
                         transitionsForEmployee.get(transitionsForEmployee.size() - 1).getMonthYear());
            }));
```

Now we get:

```
{1=[02-2016, 01-2017], 2=[02-2017, 02-2017]}
```